# WSO2 File inboundEndpoint throws exception with transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval=5000

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to set up a very simple InboundEndpoint in WSO2 5.0.0 with **transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval=5000**, but I always get the following exceptions when trying to deploy:

```
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Invalid numeric value for interval.
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.VFSProcessor.<init>(VFSProcessor.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.inboundfactory.InboundRequestProcessorFactoryImpl.createInboundProcessor(InboundRequestProcessorFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.getInboundRequestProcessor(InboundEndpoint.java:109)
    at org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint.init(InboundEndpoint.java:76)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.InboundEndpointDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(InboundEndpointDeployer.java:57)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:552)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.file.VFSProcessor.<init>(VFSProcessor.java:47)
    ... 25 more
```

Here's the full configuration as generated using the Tooling (Developer studio):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="BigBuyCategoryMapper" protocol="file" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.LockReleaseSameNode">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.AutoLockRelease">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///Users/gamac/temp/in</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///Users/gamac/temp/failed</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.DistributedLock">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">mapper_category.csv</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">5000</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///Users/gamac/temp/done</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute">none</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileSortAscending">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.CreateFolder">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">false</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.vfs.Build">false</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Please help as this is a show stopper for using WSO2 as an alternative at the moment. :(

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval">5000</parameter>
```

with

```
<parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>
```

seems to solve the issue (no more invalid format exceptions).

However this seems like a bug in the WSO2 tooling (Developer Studio) or the inboundEndpoint implementation. It's not clear what the right parameter should be ("**interval**" or "**transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval**".

The documentation describes **transport.vfs.FileProcessInterval** so it looks like that should be the correct one but it's simply not working as of 5.0.0

Comment: It is <parameter name="interval">5000</parameter>, Please  refer the sample.
https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=43995550